# linux cpu load over last X min

Tags: linux

Hello experts!
Could you please help. I want to calculate CPU load over the last 5 min. And I need to get these values permanently.

I found very useful and detailed article: http://phoxis.org/2013/09/05/finding-overall-and-per-core-cpu-utilization/
But I am not sure what is the best way on retrieving that numbers : run script every second constantly, and calculate the overage number  every 300 iteractions (for example)?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Basically I would monitor average  CPU utilization in % for last X min

Answer (score 2):

If you write your own code to monitor usage, you are up against a computing equivalent of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. Alternatively you can use the "uptime" command.

```
% uptime
  16:00:29 up 3 days, 18:31,  2 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.12, 0.09
```

The last three numbers are the system load averages over the last 1,5 and 15 minutes. From the man page:

```
   System load averages is the average number of processes that are
   either in a runnable or uninterruptable state.  A process  in  a
   runnable  state  is  either  using the CPU or waiting to use the
   CPU.  A process in uninterruptable state is waiting for some I/O
   access,  eg  waiting  for disk.  The averages are taken over the
   three time intervals.  Load averages are not normalized for  the
   number  of CPUs in a system, so a load average of 1 means a sin-
   gle CPU system is loaded all the time while on a 4 CPU system it
   means it was idle 75% of the time.
```

As long as you know how many CPUs are in your system this gives you what you need.

Second iteration:

```
# cat /proc/uptime
353615.60 344666.42
```

From the /proc man page:

```
   /proc/uptime
          This file contains two numbers: the uptime of the sys-
          tem  (seconds),  and  the amount of time spent in idle
          process (seconds).
```

You can poll this every five minutes and record the change in values.

Comment: process that is in uninterruptible state could be in that state because of I/O wait time. that means process is waiting on disk I/O. but it does not mean that CPU is busy. In other words CPU just look at the process and waits when it could be moved to the runnable queue.

Please correct me if I am mistaken :)

Comment: I wondered about that, which is why I checked the man page. As I read the extracted bit, "`a load average of 1 means a single CPU system is loaded all the time`", this seems to address that concern? Although presumably this should read a single CORE system and not a single CPU system.

Comment: Alan, could you please tell what exactly manual do you read? :)

Comment: my man proc says:
 /proc/loadavg
              The first three fields in this file are load average figures giving the number of jobs in the run queue (state R) or waiting for disk I/O (state D) average over  1,  5, and 15 minutes.    The fourth field consists of two numbers separated by a slash (/).  The first of these is the number of currently executing kernel scheduling entities (processes, threads); this will be  less  than or  equal to the number of CPUs.  The value after the slash is the number of kernel scheduling entities that currently exist on the system.

Comment: The two man pages I referenced are the `man uptime` and the `man proc`. I'm using a Debian Wheezy build.